# ActionController::RoutingError in Rails Cucumber testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to run Cucumber tests for my Rails application. I have integrated it with Selenium. On tests where I use the Capybara visit method, I get the following messages:

`Rack app ("POST /session" - (127.0.0.1)): #<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/session">`

```
unexpected response, code=500, content-type=""
      Puma caught this error: No route matches [POST] "/session" (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

I am not sure why the test is requesting that route since I have not defined it nor do I try to access it anywhere. I suspect it has something to do with Selenium, but I am unsure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your test config,

Comment: I would bet that either `visit` is overridden, or there's some other test helper that is trying to log in before browsing to where your test wants to go. Time to break out a debugger and step-step-step until you find where this is getting requested from.

Comment: This is before logging in, when I navigate to the login page to fill out information.